# How to add padding to background color of text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**I want to create a text widget the achieves what you see below:**

[image]

**I want the background color of the text to have some extra padding, but only where there is actually text.**

Currently, I have to choose between wrapping the text widget in a container widget (which then adds a background color to the empty space of a second shorter line, which I do not want). Or, I can choose to use background color for the texts' textStyle widget, but it does not respect the height(aka line-height).

Are there any ways of accomplishing this?

Comment: @rexfordkelly Thanks for the reply, but no, that is for CSS. I am trying to achieve this with Flutter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `Paint` for the `background` of `TextStyle`:

```
Text(
  'Random caption for this post1',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    background: Paint()..color = Colors.white
    ..strokeWidth = 17
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
  ),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
)
```

Result:

[image: img]

Comment: I get a `strikeThrough` on the text on above Flutter 2.5.2

Comment: @Mobina I want the text to get padding from the left and right (horizontal) only.
What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Both of the answers are hacks which don't scale well with larger text at all.
Therefore I wrote a package which is now capable to add a padding, radius and color to the text background.

Here is an image of what exactly the text of the package can do:
[image]

The link of the package is following: https://github.com/Letalus/auto_size_text_background

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've just tried the package and found no option to adjust the padding or the rounding - could you help me out with that?

Comment: Good point, I haven't released those two parameters to the AutoSizeText widget yet. Will do it soon. IMPORTANT: Due to new issues with the calculation of the text width and height, the background is currently no stable. I'm working on a fix. Once I have fixed the underlying issue, I'll update the package and my description here.

Answer (score 2):

For doing this, you can use `Column()` and add two `Containers()` for a single post text, with the below code specifications

```
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            //this is first container
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text("This is the dummy text for", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
              )
            ),
            
            //this is second container
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0), bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0))
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text("post 1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
              )
            )
          ]
        )
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does achieve that style, but I suppose this method has to be hardcoded.  I need something that is more fluid and that'll scale itself, for example, varying caption lengths.

Comment: Yeah, even I was searching for it, but it is somehow time taking. Let me see if I can come up with something. @Chrisl446 :)